# Compare Root Mean Square Values

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, t-test, mse, rms

I'm trying to compare a regression neural network to a commonly used equation. I have an 80:20 split for my training:test, and I get the root mean square error on the test set from the neural network and the equation. How can I compare the root mean square errors to see if the network is significantly better than the equation? (I've kept the splitting the same so the network and equation are tested on the same data).

I've seen stuff about bootstrapping and finding confidence intervals etc. but it is a bit confusing to be honest. What test do I use to compare the two RMSE values?

Comment: Take a look at the [Durbin-Watson test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Durbin-Watson+test).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have a look

Comment: The Diebold-Mariano test might be what you need.